# Add target="_blank" in menu items (main navigation)

Tags: 8, navigation

I use Drupal 8.9.3 with custom theme. I need to do a menu item on the main navigation who go on an external link.

I would like to add `target="_blank"` on this link, but I don't see where I can put that attribute from the user interface.

Do I need a module? I would like to avoid a PHP function.

I tried https://www.drupal.org/project/menus_attribute/releases/8.x-1.2. I added my attr but nothing appears in my code.

Comment: Both Drupal 8 (end of life) and `target="_blank"` (https://medium.com/@jitbit/target-blank-the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever-96e328301f4c) are security risks.

Answer (score 2):

The module for this is [menu_link_attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Mix](https://www.drupal.org/project/mix) module, which allow you to set id/class/target attributes and other advanced settings to menu links.
[image]
[image]